# include multiple files in YAML `in_header:`

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

In an .`rmd` document that used to compile cleanly with the YAML lines,

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    includes:
        in_header: mystyles.tex spacing.tex
 ...
```

I now get a pandoc error like `mystyles.tex spacing.tex cannot be found`
I'm now using R 3.3.2 and R Studio 1.0.153.  I had also tried several other forms (that gave different errors):

```
        in_header: "mystyles.tex" "spacing.tex"

        in_header: mystyles.tex
        in_header: spacing.tex
```

It works if I merge to LateX code in the two files, and just use

```
        in_header: mystyles.tex
```

What is the syntax for multiple files in an `in_header` line?  Has it changed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the YAML syntax for vectors (arrays). Either

```
includes:
  in_header: ["mystyles.tex", "spacing.tex"]
```

or

```
includes:
  in_header: 
    - mystyles.tex
    - spacing.tex
```

should be fine. Remember to properly indent the list under `in_header` in the latter case.

Comment: ok, but where could we have found this info.. is there a place where one can see all possible yaml options for a flexdashboard? is there an option in_body for including js code for example?